# MySQL:How to optimize this SQL?

Tags: mysql

```
select  max(id)
from pt_l_program
where starttime<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
group by lid order by null
```

Here is the result of explain :

```
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
|:---|:------------|:-------|:-----|:--------------|:----|:--------|:----|:-----|:------|
| 1  | SIMPLE      | program| ALL  | StartTime     | null| null    | null| 99999| Using where; Using temporary|
```

Comment: `ORDER BY NULL` is supposed to do what in your opinion?

Comment: How many rows match `starttime<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`? Are there start times in the future, and if so: what is the percentage?

Comment: @tadman, order b null removes a default implied filesort when using group by.  Less work server side if you don't care about ordering of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an index on the table.  One option is `pt_l_program(starttime, lid, id)`.

However, it might be better to write the query without a `group by` at the outer level.  Let me assume that you have a table with all the "l" values:

```
select (select max(p.id)
        from pt_l_program p
        where starttime <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and p.l_id = l.l_id
       )
from l
```

The above index is needed for this query as well.